# Understanding how ruby method $stdout works

Tags: ruby, stdout

Here is a simple ruby script, that takes input from a user and provides an output(yes, it will be refactored). I wanted this script to provide output into a text file, rather than console window. That was accomplished, by simply adding `$stdout = File.new('out.txt', 'w')`, but I thought that this line will just describe a variable which I will use later to tell script to use it to write output into created file.

I cant find much documentation about this method and wondering how does this program knows how to write generated output into that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$stdout` is a global variable. By default it stores an object of type [`IO`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html) associated with the standard output of the program (which is, by default, the console).

[`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) is a method of the [`Kernel` module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html) that actually calls `$stdout.send()` and pass it the list of arguments it receives. As the documentation explains, `puts(obj, ...)` is equivalent to `$stdout.puts(obj, ...)`.

Your code replaces `$stdout` with an object of type [`File`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html) that extends class `IO`. When it is created, your object opens the file `out.txt` for writing and together with its inheritance from `IO` it is fully compatible with the default behaviour of `$stdout`.

Since by default, all the output goes to `$stdout`, your new definition of `$stdout` ensures the output is written to the file `out.txt` without other changes in the code.

Comment: oh, this answer is even deeper. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`$stdout` is a global variable (as indicated by `$`) and according to the documentation, [`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) is:

> Equivalent to
>
> ```
> $stdout.puts(obj, ...)
> ```

If you assign another object to `$stdout`, then `Kernel#puts` will simply send `puts` to that object. Likewise, `print` will send `write`:

```
class Foo < BasicObject
  def puts(*args)
    ::STDOUT.puts "Foo#puts called with #{args.inspect}"
  end

  def write(*args)
    ::STDOUT.puts "Foo#write called with #{args.inspect}"
  end
end

$stdout = Foo.new

puts 'hello', 'world'
# Foo#puts called with ["hello", "world"]
print "\n"
# Foo#write called with ["\n"]
```

Note that if you assign to `$stdout`, Ruby checks whether the object responds to `write`. If not, a `TypeError` will be raised.

Comment: very nice explanation, not only about the answer to my question, but also about how to understand documentation better :)) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth highlighting the fact, mentioned by the other posts, that this is a **global** variable, and modifying it is not thread safe. For instance, if you point $stdout to a new IO stream, *anything* across the app (on that process thread) that would be logged to stdout will now be logged to your new IO stream. This can lead to multiple streams of unexpected and possibly sensitive input landing in your new IO stream.